# calculating total cost from form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have made a form in HTML and I am trying to grab the values from specific boxes to be displayed within a total cost section visible to customers.. Please check the following code#

```
<form name="myform">
    <h2>Bread Type</h2>
    <p>Please select your type of bread</p>
    <input type="text" name="example" list="exampleList">
    <datalist id="exampleList">
    <option value="Hearty Italian">
    <option value="9-Grain Wheat">
    <option value="9-Grain Honey Oat">
    <option value="Italian">
    <option value="Italian Herbs & Cheese">
    <option value="Flatbread">
    </datalist>

    <p>Please select bread size (Please note bread size differs in price)</p>
    <input type="text" name="example5" list="exampleList5">
    <datalist id="exampleList5">
    <option value="Six Inch">Six Inch (£3)</option>
    <option value="Footlong">Footlong (£5)</option>
    </datalist>

    <h2>Cheese & Toasted</h2>
    <form action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="cheese">Cheese
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="toasted">Toasted
    </form>

    <h2>Filling</h2>
    <p>Next select what you would like your sub to contain!</p>
    <input type="text" name="example2" list="exampleList2">
    <datalist id="exampleList2">
    <option value="Ham">
    <option value="Chicken & Bacon Ranch Melt">
    <option value="Cold Cut Combo">
    <option value="Italian B.M.T">
    <option value="Meatball Marinara">
    <option value="Roast Beef">
    <option value="Oven Roasted Chicken">
    <option value="Spicy Italian">
    <option value="Steak & Cheese">
    <option value="Chicken Teriyaki">
    <option value="Tuna">
    <option value="Turkey Breast">
    <option value="Turkey Breast & Ham">
    </datalist>

    <h2>Toppings</h2>
    <form action="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="lettuce">Lettuce
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="red_onion">Red Onion
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="sweetcorn">Sweetcorn
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="gherkin">Gherkin
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="red_peppers">Red Peppers
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="green_peppers">Green Pepper
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="tomato">Tomato</br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="cucumber">Cucumber
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="mayonnaise">Light Mayonnaise
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="chipotle">Chipotle Southwest
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="bbq">BBQ Sauce
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="salt">Salt
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="pepper">Pepper
    </form>

    <h2>Drink</h2>
    <input type="text" name="example3" list="exampleList3">
    <datalist id="exampleList3">
    <option value="Bottled Drink">Bottled Drink (£1)</option>
    <option value="Bottled Water">Bottled Water (80p)</option>
    <option value="Cup Drink">Cup Drink (£1)</option>
    <option value="Large Cup Drink">Large Cup Drink (£2)</option>
    </datalist>

    <h2>Cookies/Crisps</h2>
    <input type="text" name="example4" list="exampleList4">
    <datalist id="exampleList4">
    <option value="Doritos">Doritos (50p)</option>
    <option value="Walkers">Walkers (50p)</option>
    <option value="McCoys">McCoys (50p)</option>
    <option value="Quavers">Quavers (50p)</option>
    <option value="Double Chocolate Cookie">Cookies (£1)</option>
    <option value="Milk Chocolate Cookie">Cookies (£1)</option>
    <option value="Smarties Cookie">Cookies (£1)</option>
    <option value="White Chocolate Cookie">Cookies (£1)</option>
    </datalist>
    </form>
```

I would like the total to display the results from the three text boxes 'example5', 'example3' and 'example4'. Ive tried various javascript functions and it's frying my brain now. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: What JS have you tried? Can you include that in the question? Are you using any JS libraries? How do you want the results displayed? Without more context, there are too many possible solutions for us to list here.

Answer (score 1):

By giving your form elements ID's, you can easily select them with JS.  Please note your markup contained `<form>` tags within other `<form>` tags.  I've removed them and also added a button to run the function.

```js
    function viewChoices() {
        var example3 = document.getElementById("example3").value,
            example4 = document.getElementById("example4").value,
            example5 = document.getElementById("example5").value;

        alert(example3 + ' | ' + example4 + ' | ' + example5);
    }
```

```html
<form name="myform">
    <h2>Bread Type</h2>
    <p>Please select your type of bread</p>
    <input type="text" name="example" id="example" list="exampleList">
    <datalist id="exampleList">
    <option value="Hearty Italian">
    <option value="9-Grain Wheat">
    <option value="9-Grain Honey Oat">
    <option value="Italian">
    <option value="Italian Herbs & Cheese">
    <option value="Flatbread">
    </datalist>

    <p>Please select bread size (Please note bread size differs in price)</p>
    <input type="text" name="example5" id="example5" list="exampleList5">
    <datalist id="exampleList5">
    <option value="Six Inch">Six Inch (£3)</option>
    <option value="Footlong">Footlong (£5)</option>
    </datalist>

    <h2>Cheese & Toasted</h2>
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="cheese">Cheese
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="toasted">Toasted

    <h2>Filling</h2>
    <p>Next select what you would like your sub to contain!</p>
    <input type="text" name="example2" id="example2" list="exampleList2">
    <datalist id="exampleList2">
    <option value="Ham">
    <option value="Chicken & Bacon Ranch Melt">
    <option value="Cold Cut Combo">
    <option value="Italian B.M.T">
    <option value="Meatball Marinara">
    <option value="Roast Beef">
    <option value="Oven Roasted Chicken">
    <option value="Spicy Italian">
    <option value="Steak & Cheese">
    <option value="Chicken Teriyaki">
    <option value="Tuna">
    <option value="Turkey Breast">
    <option value="Turkey Breast & Ham">
    </datalist>

    <h2>Toppings</h2>
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="lettuce">Lettuce
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="red_onion">Red Onion
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="sweetcorn">Sweetcorn
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="gherkin">Gherkin
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="red_peppers">Red Peppers
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="green_peppers">Green Pepper
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="tomato">Tomato</br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="cucumber">Cucumber
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="mayonnaise">Light Mayonnaise
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="chipotle">Chipotle Southwest
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="bbq">BBQ Sauce
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="salt">Salt
    <input type="checkbox" name="topping" value="pepper">Pepper

    <h2>Drink</h2>
    <input type="text" name="example3" id="example3" list="exampleList3">
    <datalist id="exampleList3">
    <option value="Bottled Drink">Bottled Drink (£1)</option>
    <option value="Bottled Water">Bottled Water (80p)</option>
    <option value="Cup Drink">Cup Drink (£1)</option>
    <option value="Large Cup Drink">Large Cup Drink (£2)</option>
    </datalist>

    <h2>Cookies/Crisps</h2>
    <input type="text" name="example4" id="example4" list="exampleList4">
    <datalist id="exampleList4">
    <option value="Doritos">Doritos (50p)</option>
    <option value="Walkers">Walkers (50p)</option>
    <option value="McCoys">McCoys (50p)</option>
    <option value="Quavers">Quavers (50p)</option>
    <option value="Double Chocolate Cookie">Cookies (£1)</option>
    <option value="Milk Chocolate Cookie">Cookies (£1)</option>
    <option value="Smarties Cookie">Cookies (£1)</option>
    <option value="White Chocolate Cookie">Cookies (£1)</option>
    </datalist>

    <button onClick="viewChoices()">View Choices</button>
    </form>
```